# Cypress: how to drag an element towards another dynamic element

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress

In cypress I'm trying to drag one element towards another element?

How can I do that?

It should look something like this

```
cy.('@firstElememt').trigger('drag').to('@secondElement').trigger('drop');
```

The problem is that the second element location is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Try Cypress cypress-drag-drop.

Below is the link:
https://github.com/4teamwork/cypress-drag-drop